# Where can I find datasets to predict rainfall for a certain city?

Tags: data-request, weather, climate

I am seeking datasets for predicting rainfall with the help of the following variables:

1. Temperature
2. Wind Speed
3. Humidity
4. Air Pressure
5. Quantity of Rainfall

Please suggest and advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing Copernicus, they provide API for accessing climate & other kinds of data: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu

Comment: Interestingly, saw their data on the news today for the cleanest air. Interesting!